# Como puedo cambiar mi pantalla de inicio al cerrar la App en Flutter

Tags: flutter, app

Necesito ayuda para cambiar el main() de mi app, después de ingresar por primera vez, al presionar el botón me envié a la pantalla 2, y, al cerrar mi app y volver a abrir, solo me cargue la pantalla 2.
Es esto posible? espero algún tipo de ayuda gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, por favor daté una vuelta por [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Sería de mucha ayuda para los miembros de la comunidad ver el código que usas, porque podrían ser cientos de cosas lo que te generan ese problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el package de [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

Puedes usar este [ejemplo](https://gist.github.com/DevKhalyd/27e44a6b00bae219fe58191d4dd1dcd4) para implementar las Shared Preferences

1. Cuando pases a tu siguiente pantalla guardas el valor en las shareds prefs
2. Cuando vuelvas a abrir tu app primero lees el valor que guardaste y si ese coincide pues abres la segunda pantalla.